# How to save a variable in a hta, so that after closing and opening the hta, it will be saved?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hta

I am trying to make a hta (html application) where you can add names to an array, and then find out if a certain name is in the array. When I close and reopen the hta (or refresh for a html), none of the names are saved. How do I make it so that when I run the function for adding a name, the code saves with the variable having the name in it.

this is the function for adding a name

```
    var names = []
    function addName(first, last){
    names.push(first + " " + last)
}

function realAddName(eventObject){
    var addFirstName = document.getElementById("addFirstName")//the input box for the first name
    var addLastName = document.getElementById("addLastName")//the input box for the last name
    addName(addFirstName.value, addLastName.value)
    alert("The name you input is now added to the thing.")
}
```

I don't have jQuery, so do not give me answers that use jQuery.

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

That's now how javascript works.  When the browser is closed any values that you'ved added to the array do not get saved.  This is the role of the database. jQuery wouldn't be able to accomplish this either.

Comment: What is a database and how do I use it?

Comment: What is a data base and how do you make one/use one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist your application's state to disk. Because this is a HTA it means you can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to interact with the local filesystem.

```
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var textFile = fs.CreateTextFile("foo.txt");
textFile.WriteLine(someVariable);
textFile.Close();
```

- `fs` is an object that gives you access to the local filesystem: `FileSystemObject`
- `FileSystemObject` has a method called `CreateTextFile` that creates a new textfile on disk and gives you an object (`textFile`) you can use to write text to this file.
- `WriteLine` writes some text to the file
  `.Close()` causes the textfile to be "saved" safely.

Comment: Can you explain it in a more simplified way of what this does?

Comment: Is it possible to use an array instead of a text file? Also, how would I search to see something is in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Local storage maybe will help you. For example:

```
function addName(first, last) {
    localStorage.setItem("usr123", first + " " + last)
}
```

You can add, change, or remove your data in local storage. But it's limited. You can find out more about localStorage here: [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

user2216996

If you really need to ask then you don't need a database for what you are doing. Try the "Hey, Scripting Guy!" solution at http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/11/09/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-save-information-in-an-hta-as-a-tab-separated-values-file.aspx

If you really want to learn about databases then I suggest that you go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database and start reading.